# Using NSLayoutAnchor to create constraints between two labels?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, nslayoutanchor

I'm creating a view programmatically and need to set constraints between two labels. I recently just discovered NSLayoutAnchor and feel it would be a good choice to use it but I'm unsure how to create constraints between two different things (ie labels, imageViews, etc).  I know a general setup will look something like this:

```
let codedLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
codedLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
codedLabel.textAlignment = .center
codedLabel.text = alertText
codedLabel.numberOfLines=1
codedLabel.textColor=UIColor.red
codedLabel.font=UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
codedLabel.backgroundColor=UIColor.lightGray

self.contentView.addSubview(codedLabel)
codedLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
codedLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
codedLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
codedLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codedLabel.superview!.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
codedLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codedLabel.superview!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

How would you set up constraints in between two labels?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two `UIViews` you wish to lay out *horizontally* in one of two ways:

- View #1 is 20 points from the leading edge of the superview's margin or safe area and View #2 is another 20 points from view #1. (Think of a left-justified row of buttons.)
- Both views are to be centered, with equal spacing before/between/after each view. (Think of two buttons spaced equally apart and centered.)

For example #1 the code would be:

```
// #1
let view1 = UIView()
view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(view1)
let view2 = UIView()
view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(view2)

// #2
let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
view.addLayoutGuide(margins)
view1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

// #3
view2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

// #4
view1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
view2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

**Comment #1:** Note that you *do not need* to give each view a frame, but you *do need* to set the auto-resizing mask to false. This is a mistake many new coders forget.

**Comment #2:** All `UIViewController` main views have a `layoutMarginGuide` that yield standard margins both vertically and horizontally (and in iOS 11, particularly for iPhone X, there is a new `safeAreaLayoutGuide` for *vertical* alignment). I've set the leading edge of `view1` to be the leading edge of the `margin` with an additional constant of 20 points from it.

**Comment #3:** Just like I related `view1` to the `margin`, I'm relating `view2` to `view1, but this time the leading edge of`view2`is 20 points from the`view1` *trailing* edge.

**Comment #4:** The last thing you need to do for *horizontal* placement is to give each view a width. In this case I wanted both to be 100 points.

Example #2 pretty much uses the same code as example #1, so I'll note the key differences only:

```
let view1 = UIView()
view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(view1)
let view2 = UIView()
view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(view2)

let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
view.addLayoutGuide(margins)

// #1
let spacer1 = UILayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(spacer1)
let spacer2 = UILayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(spacer2)
let spacer3 = UILayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(spacer3)

// #2
spacer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
view1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spacer1.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
spacer2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
view2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spacer2.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
spacer3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view2.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
spacer3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

// #3
view1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
view2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
spacer1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spacer2.widthAnchor).isActive = true
spacer2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spacer3.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

**Comment #1:** In iOS 9 Apple introduced the concept of `UILayoutGuides`. Before this, to create "spacers" you had to actually create an invisible `UIView` and add it as a subview (with all the overhead associated with it). Layout guides "act" like views but do not have that overhead.

**Comment #2:** The horizontal sequence if "margin...spacer1...view1...spacer2...view2...spacer3...margin". Note that I'm *not* using any constants, as I wish to let the layout engine give equal spacing.

**Comment #3:** While I *am* giving width values for both views, I am not with the spacers. Instead, I am declaring their widths to be equal.

Please note that I've only worked with *horizontal* constraints. For auto layout to work, you also need to declare *vertical* constraints too. Most of the concepts are the same... instead of leading/trailing, centerX, and width anchors you have top/bottom, centerY, and height ones. BUT! Starting with iOS 11 you now have a `safeAreaLayoutGuide` that you should be using instead of `layoutMarginsGuide`. This only applies to vertical! That's why I separated things. Here's the code I use to work with vertical alignment:

```
let layoutGuideTop = UILayoutGuide()
let layoutGuideBottom = UILayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(layoutGuideTop)
view.addLayoutGuide(layoutGuideBottom)
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    layoutGuideTop.topAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(guide.topAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
    layoutGuideBottom.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(guide.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
} else {
    layoutGuideTop.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    layoutGuideBottom.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Now you have `layoutGuideTop` and `layoutGuideBottom` that should work regardless of what iOS version is running.